# Django 1.7 on App Engine "ImportError: No module named msvcrt"

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to upgrade Django to version 1.7 on a Google App Engine development server running on my Windows machine.

When trying to load the app, I get the following exception from `doango\core\files\locks.py`:

```
ImportError: No module named msvcrt
```

The relevant code lines are:

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    import msvcrt
```

I guess the exception is raised because App Engine's dev server doesn't supply a version of msvcrt, but because my dev machine is Windows, os.name is still `'nt'`.

Is there a solution or a workaround for this?

Relevant stacktrace:

```
 File "...\django\core\files\locks.py", line 30, in <module>
    import msvcrt
 File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py", line 852, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
```

Comment: @karthikr msvcrt is a Windows only package, and is part of the python standard library. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html

Comment: You could try to include/symlink `msvcrt` in your application directory to make the dev server see it, just make sure not to upload it to GAE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found a workaround. In `appengine_config.py` add the following lines:

```
import os

on_appengine = os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE','').startswith('Development')
if on_appengine and os.name == 'nt':
    os.name = None
```

I'm still looking for a less hackish solution.

Comment: This is clever and I'm unsure if it will cause bugs since the os isn't *actually* nt. But it is clever.

Comment: @Nick I've been using this for over a year now and it works well.

Comment: Great to know. I guess there's no problem using msvcrt as a stand-alone, separate from the intended OS. Interesting!

Comment: @Tzach where the file `appengine_config.py` resides? I can't seem to find it anywhere

Comment: @har07 you need to create it in the root folder of your app, where your `app.yaml` is

Answer (score 2):

I found this issue while using [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).  I created a new Python GAE project and indicated I wanted to include Flask.  I encountered a couple of small issues while getting it up and running and this was the last one: as @Tzach pointed out, you will eventually run in to a `ImportError: No module named msvcrt` while running one of these GAE/Flask/JetBrains boilerplates.  Tzach's hack, however, didn't work for me -- they must have changed the Click library to detect the host OS in a different way.  The solution for me ended up being the following code within `appengine_config.py`:

```
on_appengine = os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE','').startswith('Development')

if on_appengine and os.name == 'nt':
  sys.platform = "Not Windows"
```

The reason it changed is because it appears that Click is now using the following code to detect the OS:

```
WIN = sys.platform.startswith('win')
```

Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Devserver doesn't provide access to modules that are on your system. It only looks at modules that are in your project. This is to ensure that if it runs on devserver, it will run when deployed. Either use the patched version of Django on your devserver, understanding that the OS will never be 'nt' on App Engine, or import msvcrt into your project so it can be found and put a skip_files line in app.yaml when you deploy, since it will never be needed when deployed to App Engine's non-windows environment.