# Unable to run AppEngine django application locally

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I am on **windows 10**, Installed **python 2.7.11**.I have a app engine application.I am able to run it locally with django, It is working perfectly.But when I am trying to run it via **dev_appengine.py** I am getting this error.

***[image: importerror-no-module-named-msvcrt]***

Already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915164/django-1-7-on-app-engine-importerror-no-module-named-msvcrt)

Comment: Please don't post text as images...

Comment: What version of Django are you using?  You cannot use the standard Django.  You must use a modified package, like django-nonrel or djangae.

Comment: Or, the GAE library, with some limitations.  See Django at:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27.  If you use the library in your `app.yaml`, you don't also add it in your `lib`.

Comment: @GAEfan , If you mean to say RTFM , That's where i am coming from. Please comment only if you could help.By the way am using django 1.9.7

Comment: This is the problem : " am using django 1.9.7"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915164/django-1-7-on-app-engine-importerror-no-module-named-msvcrt?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Don't mind, Got it working on my linux box without any changes.There are something better done on linux than windows.Anyways thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please include this code in your appengine_config.py file,

```
import os

on_appengine = os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE','').startswith('Development')
if on_appengine and os.name == 'nt':
    os.name = None
```