# global name '_dlopen' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, virtualenv

I'm using GAE sandbox on Windows, python 2.7 and virtualenv.
When I try to use Requests lib, I'm getting the following error:

```
global name '_dlopen' is not defined
```

Full stack:

```
INFO     2017-09-20 13:40:20,551 module.py:821] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 
        from ctypes import (c_buffer, POINTER, byref, create_unicode_buffer,
    File "c:\python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 450, in <module>
        pythonapi = PyDLL(None)
    File "c:\python27\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 362, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    NameError: global name '_dlopen' is not defined
```

GAE on windows did have issues with loading ctypes and and winreg but it's now whitelisted on development environment automatically.

What am I missing?

Comment: I have the same problem specific to Windows 10. Uninstalled/reinstalled everything, no joy at all. Followed all installation instructions from Google etc. explicitly (and several times to ensure I didn't miss anything).

Setup is very simple; a local SDK GAE project, hello-world quality, attempting to use Flask. Very bare-bones. Python 2.7, the usual base required GAE stuff.

Same procedure/app code runs on the Mac. I understand installed underpinnings are different, but it would seem this development is problematic on Windows (there's also the mrcv package problem, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found what caused the issue:
It was the workaround suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25915535/3767514

The problem was that changing `os.name=None` meant ctypes cannot use the correct dll load library.

ctypes **init** line 457:

```
if _os.name in ("nt", "ce"):
windll = LibraryLoader(WinDLL)
```

so the solution was importing ctypes before changing the os.name to None in appengine_config.py:

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
import ctypes
os.name = None
```